# Menu scroll animate in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a code that when I click the menu it finds the anchor tag with animation in scrolling but this day, my code suddenly wont work, I did not touch my code what happen?

This is my html code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list flex-column mb-4 show-bg-active" id="sidebarList">
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#who-we-are">Who We Are</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#history">History</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#mission-vision">Mission &amp; Vision</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#leadership">Leadership</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="who-we-are" class="mb-4">WHO WE ARE</section>
<section id="history" class="mb-4">HISTORY</section>
<section id="mission-vision" class="mb-4">MISSION AND VISION</section>
<section id="leadership" class="mb-4">LEADERSHIP</section>
<section id="partners" class="mb-4">PARTNERS</section>
```

This is my script:

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('section[id="' + this.hash.slice(1) + '"]').offset().top-100
    }, 800);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: what is the error on console?

Comment: Can you send the URL of the page?

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine. you need to set `min-height`.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('section[id="' + this.hash.slice(1) + '"]').offset().top-100
    }, 800);
    return false;
});
```

```css
.mb-4{
  min-height:250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-list flex-column mb-4 show-bg-active" id="sidebarList">
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#who-we-are">Who We Are</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#history">History</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#mission-vision">Mission &amp; Vision</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#leadership">Leadership</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="who-we-are" class="mb-4">WHO WE ARE</section>
<section id="history" class="mb-4">HISTORY</section>
<section id="mission-vision" class="mb-4">MISSION AND VISION</section>
<section id="leadership" class="mb-4">LEADERSHIP</section>
<section id="partners" class="mb-4">PARTNERS</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
}

ul {
   height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-list flex-column mb-4 show-bg-active" id="sidebarList">
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#who-we-are">Who We Are</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#history">History</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#mission-vision">Mission &amp; Vision</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#leadership">Leadership</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-hash data-hash-offset="110" href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="who-we-are" class="section mb-4">WHO WE ARE</section>
<section id="history" class="section mb-4">HISTORY</section>
<section id="mission-vision" class="section mb-4">MISSION AND VISION</section>
<section id="leadership" class="section mb-4">LEADERSHIP</section>
<section id="partners" class="section mb-4">PARTNERS</section>
```

I have edit you fiddle you can check it out

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ek1nzsrn/)